# Does strongly monotone preference imply local non-satiation?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

How to prove this? I understand monotonicity implies local non-satiation but does strongly monotone also imply it? How to prove it like this - https://felixmunozgarcia.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/recitation_1.pdf (page 4 answer(b))?

Comment: Yes because Strong monotonicity implies monotonicity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Suppose not, then there exists some $x \in X, \varepsilon > 0$ such that $u(x) > u(x') \; \forall \;x' : \|x - x'\| < \varepsilon$, which is the definition of a local maximum and contradicts strict monotonicity.